# Check if user have a specific id in database

Tags: php, sql

I want to know how can I check The specific order id are in the user database

the order_id column have multiple data like this: `1,2,3,4,5` each user have a unique id

I don't know how to do this and get the user data based on the specific order id

so the example I have a specific order id, let's say **5**

and I want to know which user that have order id **5**

I have tried with SQL LIKE Operator and SQL IN Operator, but it doesn't work

```
$userdata = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE order_id LIKE '%5%'")->fetch_assoc();
$userdata->order_id; //show 1,2,3,4,5
```

user table

```
user_id | order_id
1       | 1,2,3,4,5
2       | 6,7,8,9,10
3       | 11,12,13,14,15
4       | 16,17,18,19,20
5       | 21,22,23,24,25
```

Comment: Fix your data model.  Any time you have a string of delimited values in a column, what you *probably* want is multiple records with one value in each record.  Then you can just query which records have that specific `order_id`.

Comment: `WHERE order_id LIKE '%,5,%' OR order_id LIKE '5,%' OR order_id LIKE '%,5'`... etc. Then deal with the results in your PHP. Or, design your database properly!

Comment: ```select user_id from user 
 where CONCAT(',' , order_id, ',') like '%,5,%';```